# How to match and replace values in different columns in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I match and replace values in different columns in Pandas Dataframe?
So for example, if my df looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
d = {'reference_id': ['10.234','11.234','12.234','13.234','14.324'], 
      'word': ['word1', 'word2', '=11.234','word4','=10.234']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

  reference_id     word
0       10.234    word1
1       11.234    word2
2       12.234  =11.234
3       13.234    word4
4       14.324  =10.234
```

What do I have to do to replace the reference_ids in the word column with the matching words? So that it transforms into this:

```
  reference_id   word
0       10.234  word1
1       11.234  word2
2       12.234  word2
3       13.232  word4
4       14.324  word1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `replace`

```
df.word = df.word.str.strip('=').replace(dict(zip(df.reference_id,df.word)))
Out[88]: 
0    word1
1    word2
2    word2
3    word4
4    word1
Name: word, dtype: object
```